# Can Xamarin.iOS use SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, swiftui

Currently, for building `Xamarin.iOS` apps, there is a documented way to build `UI` in `Xcode` with `InterfaceBuilder` and then use it in the Xamarin.iOS project.

Question:

Is there a way to build UI with SwiftUI and use it in an existing Xamarin.iOS project?

Comment: https://github.com/chkn/Xamarin.SwiftUI

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/chkn/Xamarin.SwiftUI which is a C# binding to SwiftUI via Xamarin.